# How to convert $V \otimes W^*$ to a matrix space?

Tags: vectors, tensors

Namely let's say we have chosen basises $e_1, e_2, ... e_k$ for $V$ and $j_1, j_2, ... j_n$ for $W$. Now, since we can always just convert them separately, and then add the matrixes, how we represent $v \otimes w^*$ as a matrix given the above basises? Is the answer related to the notation that when vectors from a space are represented by column vectors, the vectors from the dual space are represented as row vectors?

Also, is there any significance of the how many pure tensors a matrix is made up of?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: This is a pure math question, and hence off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

For $v_i\in V,w_i^*\in W^*$, we can see $\sum_i v_i\otimes w_i^*$ as  an element of $Hom(W,V)$, by setting :
$$ \forall w\in W, \qquad (\sum_i v_i\otimes w_i^*)(w)= \sum_i w_i^*(w)v_i. \quad (A)  $$

Let $(j_1^*,\cdots,j_n^*)$ be the dual base of $B_W=(j_1,\cdots,j_n)$.

(a) The matrix of  $\:e_i\otimes j_l^*$ in the bases you gave $(B_W \: and \:  (e_1, \cdots,e_k)\:)$ is a $k\times n$ matrix $M_{il}=(m_{\alpha \beta})_{(\alpha,\beta)\in [1,k] \times [1,n]}$ (k rows, n colomns) where all the entries are zero except  $m_{il}=1$ (you can compute it using (A)).

(b) Now if u take $v\otimes w^*$ with $v=\sum_sv_se_s$ and $w^*=\sum_r w_rj_r^*$, where $v_s$ and $w_r$ are scalars, u get :
$$v\otimes w^*=\sum_{s,r} v_sw_r \:(e_s\otimes j_r^*).$$ 
So the matrix of $v\otimes w^*$, in the basis as before, is :
$$\sum_{r,s}v_sw_r\: M_{s,r},$$ 
where $M_{s,r}$ is as in (a), and the matrix of $v\otimes w^*$ has entries : $v_sw_r$ (row s, column r).

(c) Finaly notice that this matrix correspond to the Kronecker product of the "vectors" $Mat(v)$ and $Math(w^*)$, where $Math(v)=(v_1,\cdots,v_k)$ is the decomposition of $v$ in the basis $(e_1,\cdots,e_k)$, and $Math(w^*)=(w_1,\cdots,w_n)$ is the decomposition of $w^*$ in $(j_1^*,\cdots,j_n^*)$.